# str_splt_fixed from right to left

Tags: r, stringr

I've tried searching for this and am sure the answer is out there but no luck.

I'm trying to use `stringr` package, but to have it read the text line from right to left.

```
library(stringr)
fruits <- c("apples and oranges and pears and bananas", "pineapples and mangos and guavas")
str_split_fixed(fruits, " and ", 3)
```

This returns:

```
"apples"     "oranges" "pears and bananas"
"pineapples" "mangos" "guavas"
```

I'm trying to get it to return:

```
"apples and oranges" "pears" "bananas"
"pineapples" "mangos" "guavas"
```

Comment: `rev(str_split_fixed(fruits, " and ", 3))`?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible with `str_split_fixed()`

Comment: Thanks Pascal - that worked for the example I gave but it doesn't seem to be working for the application that I am applying it too. . .  apologies

I edited the above. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be in base, `stringr` or `stringi` but you can kinda implement it on your own:

```
sapply(stri_split_fixed(stri_reverse(fruits), " dna ", 3)[[1]], stri_reverse, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
## [1] "bananas"            "pears"              "apples and oranges"
```

and, for your larger example data:

```
fruits <- c("apples and oranges and pears and bananas", 
            "pineapples and mangos and guavas")

do.call(rbind, lapply(stri_reverse(fruits), function(x) {
  rev(sapply(stri_split_fixed(x, " dna ", 3)[[1]], stri_reverse, USE.NAMES=FALSE))
}))

##      [,1]                 [,2]     [,3]              
## [1,] "apples and oranges" "pears"  "bananas"
## [2,] "pineapples"         "mangos" "guavas"
```

Also, a modified version of Richard's adaptation:

```
matrix(rev(stri_reverse(str_split_fixed(stri_reverse(fruits), 
                                        stri_reverse(" and "), 3))),
       nrow=length(fruits), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

which is prbly more efficient.

Comment: And also the ridiculousness of `library(stringi); rev(stri_reverse(str_split_fixed(stri_reverse(fruits), stri_reverse(" and "), 3)))` Boom